# Create non-durable subscriber in MQ

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to create new subscriber with 'Destination name' as local-queue-name, but for that I need non-durable subscriber.

When creating new subscriber in MQ, using MQSC or MQ-Explorer, how do I make it non-durable?

Is there any way to change it (alter) after it has been created?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Non-durable subscriptions are active as long as the application that created them is active. Once the application ends or application closes connection to queue manager, these subscriptions are removed. What this means is non-durable subscriptions can only be created programmatically using MQSUB(in C language) or it's equivalent method in Java/C#.

Non-durable subscriptions can not be created using MQSC or MQExplorer. You can create durable subscriptions using MQSC/MQExplorer.

Answer (score 0):

Non-durable subscriptions exist only as long as the subscribing application's connection to the queue manager remains open. The subscription is removed when the subscribing application disconnects from the queue manager either deliberately or by loss of connection. When the connection is closed, the information about the subscription is removed from the queue manager, and will no longer be shown if you display subscriptions using the `DISPLAY SBSTATUS` command. No more messages will be put to the subscriber queue.

For more information, see [Subscription durability](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.amqnar.doc/ps22060_.htm)